# Multiple risk ratio analysis or single multiple logistic regression for survey

Tags: logistic, survey, odds-ratio, epidemiology, relative-risk

I was asked by a doctoral student to analyze the answers to an old questionnaire her lab has and would like to publish the results of.
There are a few questions with regards to animal care and disease history. The animals in those farms were also tested at the same time for a specific disease.

I would like to correctly report the association strength between the animal care and vaccination history for the specific disease.

The dataset is tabular, completely categorical, but there a few non-binary variables.

My first thought was to use binary logistic regression, get reasonable variables with p <0.1 and construct a multiple logistic regression. Then I could report the adjusted odds ratio for each variable with p <0.05. The disease is present in 5% of the cases, so I think it's okay to rationalize that the odds ratio ~ relative risk.

Lately, I have read about risk ratio, and that I could calculate it individually for each variable and disease. Could I present this result, or does the presence of other variables make this wrong?

Is this the correct way?

**Update**

*Thanks Mike for the grammar help!*

I am leaving previous content for context. Below I added some fictious data in the same structure as my data.

**Data**

$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline Name & Event A & Event B & Vaccine A & Target \\ \hline Farm1 & Present & Not Present & Used & Negative \\ \hline Farm2 & Not Present & Present & Used & Positve \\ \hline Farm3 & Not Present & Not Present & Not Used & Positive \\ \hline  \end{array}$

My doubt is how to correctly analyze and report this data. My first thought was to do a multiple logistic regression using glm in R.

$ target \tilde{} \beta1EventA + \beta2EventB + \beta3VaccineA $

From the coefficients I would get the adjusted odds ratio.

$OR_{eventA} = e^{\beta1}$

Later, I found that i could also calculate the individual relative risk for variable target, creating multiple 2x2 tables.

$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline  & Y=1 & Y=0 \\ \hline E=1 & 20 & 90 \\ \hline E=0 & 250 & 600 \\ \hline  \end{array}$

$RR = \frac{20}{270}\times\frac{690}{90}$

Because of the presence of more variables in the regression the coefficients are different, and in this lay my doubt.

Should I do one of the analysis or could I do both, and report as different meanings?

Ps: I also tried to find a book that could explain in more details this theme, but I could not find. If you could suggest some books, sites, articles, I will be grateful.

Comment: This always depends on the research question. First consideration from my point of view would be whether the number of variables is low enough that you may not need any variable selection at all, because your idea (and any variable selection) runs the risk that you lose valuable information (two variables may be highly related, both large p, but you may need at least one). Next thing is that in logistic regression some x-variables explain a y, which is asymmetric, whereas you write that you're interested in association, which is symmetric. Hard to make recommendation here without knowing more.

Comment: @Lewian I added fake data and some more structure to the question. If you could check and help, I will be grateful!

Comment: 1) It looks now like in fact you want to explain or predict a target variable from influence factors, so logistic regression should be fine. 2) Number of variables looks low, I wouldn't do variable selection based on p-values (I don't see any reason for doing that, you may have one that I don't know). 3) Odds ratios vs. relative risk still depends on the aim. Who is your audience, what do they want to know? There's nothing wrong with the adjusted odds ratio. Individual relative risk may be of interest but interpretation  needs to take into account that there are other variables.